# How do I get the K8s `ca.crt` and `ca.key` running K8s on a service provider(GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Note: I am not running locally on Minikube or something, but GKE - but could be any provider.

I want to be able to create users/contexts in K8s with openssl:

```
openssl x509 -req -in juan.csr -CA CA_LOCATION/ca.crt -CAKey CA_LOCATION/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out juan.crt -days 500
```

How do I get the K8s `ca.crt` and `ca.key`? - I found this for `ca.crt`, but is this the way and still missing the ca.key?

```
kubectl get secret -o jsonpath="{.items[?(@.type==\"kubernetes.io/service-account-token\")].data['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode
```

And, other way than logging into master node `/etc/kubernetes/pki/.`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest viewing the following [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/#openssl) on how to generate a ca.key and ca.crt for your kubernetes cluster. Please keep in mind this is not an official google document, however this may help you achieve what you are looking for.

Here are the commands found in the document.

Generate ca.key: `openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048`

Generate ca.cert: `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -subj "/CN=${MASTER_IP}" -days 10000 -out ca.crt`

EDIT

I found 2 unsupported documents [[1]](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/) [[2]](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/sign-server-and-client-certificates.html#create-a-key) on generating a certificate and key with openssl, it should be applicable with kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks, but I still need the cert and key ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  Google do not expose the keys as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-trust#root_of_trust).

Specifically and I quote:

> An internal Google service manages root keys for this CA, which are non-exportable. This service accepts certificate signing requests, including those from the kubelets in each GKE cluster. Even if the API server in a cluster were compromised, the CA would not be compromised, so no other clusters would be affected.

Using Kubernetes v1.19 and higher you can sign your CSR using the Kubernetes API itself as referenced [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/).

Encode your CSR `$ ENCODED=$(cat mia.csr | base64 | tr -d "\n")`.

Then post it to k8s:

```
$ cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: mia
spec:
  request: $ENCODED
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
  #expirationSeconds: 86400  # Only supported on >=1.22
  usages:
  - client auth
EOF
```

And then approve the CSR:

```
$ kubectl certificate approve mia
certificatesigningrequest.certificates.k8s.io/mia approved
```

Then download the signed certificate:

```
kubectl get csr mia -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}'| base64 -d > mia.crt
```

I wrote an example of the end to end flow [here](https://medium.com/@mattgillard/creating-a-kubernetes-rbac-user-in-google-kubernetes-engine-gke-fa930217a052).